# How to show all tick labels in holoviews?

Tags: python, holoviews

I have this [holoviews.Image Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vG08Y.png). I relabeled the y-axis using `yticks` argument but I need to show all tickmarks, like this using [holoviews.HeatMap Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRjSI.png). I don't want to use the HeatMap for a couple of reasons:
1) Takes too long to render, 
2) Doesn't link using `RangeTool` with `holoviews.Curve` objects.

```
data = np.random.rand(10,100)
xticks = list(zip(range(100), pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=100)))
yticks = list(zip(range(10),list('ABCDEFGHIJ')))
image= hv.Image(data).opts(cmap='RdBu_r', colorbar=True, 
                             default_tools=['hover'],
                             height=300, width=800, 
                             xlabel='', xticks=xticks, 
                             ylabel='', yticks=yticks)
image
```

Comment: Hi Dastan, Can you put up a sample of your data and code to reproduce your plots? Makes it easier to help.

Comment: Thanks! The above code produces [this image](https://imgur.com/a/NN4V3m1).

Comment: i looked at it, but didn't know how to solve it, you can also post your question here: https://gitter.im/pyviz/pyviz